# return data with count from two tables in mysql query

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables in my database; groups and members.
groups has the following columns: id, name, description, owner_id, school_id
members has the following columns: id, user_id, group_id

I want to return all the records in group, on each row it should perform a count on the members table to determine how many members each group has.

so my end result should be like this:
id, name, description, owner_id, school_id, count(this is from the members table)

i keep trying but sometimes when i have only 2 groups but 3 members i get 5 rows returned instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is with `COUNT()`, a `LEFT JOIN` and a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT g.*, COUNT(m.id) as member_count
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN members m
ON m.group_id = g.id
GROUP BY g.id
```

For performance, ensure you have an index on `members.group_id`.